# BootstrapContext in claimsprincipal null

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, wif

We are using WIF in out MVC 4 web application. We also have set up an authentication with an STS.

So far, so good. Now the problem: When we login and return to the website we can see our username. We are also able to logout.
Because of securityreasons we make use of the bootstrap token to secure calls to out API. Problem is that after login the bootstrap token is NULL, while the claims are present.
When the apppool is recycled or the website is rebuild in Visual Studio, the token is present and shown on the website.

This is how we get the token now:

```
var claimsPrincipal = (ClaimsPrincipal)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
var bootstrapContext = (BootstrapContext)claimsPrincipal.Identities.First().BootstrapContext;

ViewBag.Token = bootstrapContext.Token;
```

Does anyone knows how to get the token without recycling the app pool or rebuilding the website?

Comment: Are you enable saving bootstrap token in web.config? <microsoft.identityModel>
 <service saveBootstrapTokens="true">
  ...
 </service>
</microsoft.identityModel>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to retrieve it from the SecurityToken property on BootstrapContext, assuming that the property value is not null.

The following code snippet extracts a SAML token from the security token and writes it to a string builder:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder)) {
    new SamlSecurityTokenHandler(new SamlSecurityTokenRequirement()).WriteToken(writer, bootstrapContext.SecurityToken);
}

var tokenXml = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Okay, I tried it in a test application and works like a charm! Thanks!